# Perguntas específicas de um contexto de erro comentado pelo próprio inquiridor que ficam abandonadas

Tags: debate

Às vezes me deparo com algumas perguntas que parecem não ter muito sentido, e depois a própria pessoa que fez a pergunta faz um comentário dizendo que na verdade não funcionava porquê ela havia esquecido algo. Aí essa pergunta fica, digamos... "à deriva" e sem respostas, ninguém mais dá atenção ela.

Minha dúvida é: essas questões não deveriam ser fechadas?

[Aqui um exemplo de uma pergunta desse tipo.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224992/erro-ao-passar-parametro-para-a-fun%C3%A7ao-user-set-password)

Comment: Dever deveriam, mas dependendo do dia e horario que elas são postadas, podem se perder na pagina ou as pessoas com esse privilégio não a viram.

Comment: Geralmente quando acontece algo assim, devemos incentivar quem perguntou a responder a pergunta com a solução encontrada com o voto de "pergunta respondida"

Answer (score 12):

Basta votar para fechar que ela vai para fila de análise:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close

E os usuários com reputação suficiente irão ser "informados" (quando entrarem na fila) e votarão se assim desejarem/acreditarem que deva ser fechada.

Se você ainda não puder votar para fechar ([requer 3k](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) use o botão "sinalizar":

> [image: sinalizar]

No `Fechar` já existe a opção:

- <kbd>fora de escopo...</kbd> > <kbd>Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.</kbd>

E no `Sinalizar`:

- <kbd>deveria ser fechada...</kbd> > <kbd>fora de escopo...</kbd> > <kbd>Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.</kbd>

O sistema já lhe dá todas ferramentas para seguir com uma auditoria sobre as postagens, qualquer dúvida consulte o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help, tem muita informação lá.